# Arduino Serial.read can't add to a string

Tags: c++, arduino, xbee

I have this code:

```
void setup()
{
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  AtInit();
  SendAt("RE");
  xbeeLow = SendAt("SL");
  xbeeFirmware = SendAt("VR");
  xbeeHardware = SendAt("HV");
  SendAt("WR");
  closeAt();
}

bool AtInit(){
  int loopCount = 0;
  leds.setPixelColor(1, amber);
  leds.show();
  while(1){
    delay(1100);
    Serial.print("+++");
    delay(1100);
    String atInitResult = ReadLine( 1000 );
    if(atInitResult){
      leds.setPixelColor(1, green);
      leds.show();
      return true;
    }
    if(loopCount == 3){
      leds.setPixelColor(1, red);
      leds.show();
      return false;
    }else{
      loopCount += 1;  
    }
  }
}

String ReadLine( unsigned long timeout ){
  char inByte;
  unsigned long readLineStart = millis();
  String response;
  delay(timeout);
  while(1){
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
      inByte = Serial.read();
      Serial.print(inByte);
      if(inByte == '\r'){
        response = dataString;
        dataString = "";
        break;
      }
      dataString += inByte;
    }    
  }
  return response;
}

String SendAt( String command ){
  String atResponse;
  String atClose;
  Serial.println("AT" + command);
  atResponse = ReadLine( 500 );
  Serial.print(F("*********>"));
  Serial.print(atResponse);
  Serial.println(F("<*********"));
  return atResponse;

}
```

The `sendAt` fucntion calls the `Readline` to get Data from an xbee in AT command mode.

The `Serial.print`s are for debuging purpose.
Here is what i got on my terminal screen

```
+++OK
ATRE
OK
*********>OK<*********
ATSL
40B23B83
*********>40<*********
ATVR
8070
*********><*********
ATHV
2342
*********><*********
ATWR
OK
*********><*********
ATCN
OK
```

Why does the `Serial.print` just after the `Serial.read()` of the `char` itself acutally print the good caracter, even though the `dataString += inByte` doesn't seem to add the `char` to the actual string? It seems to work for the first few commands only, after that it doesn't add more.

Comment: Where is `dataString` instantiated?

Comment: I have tried to initlize it inside the function since i don't need it anywhere else but on this exemple it is initalized at the begining of the code as a String.

Comment: Personally I HATE using variable buffers for arduino... Use a fixed one instead of wasting lots of time and memory for reallocating the string. Then... Are you using the SAME serial for both the debugging and the xbee? This does not seem a good idea since you are sending back to the xbee the commands received fom it. Third comment: how do you know that Third: I think that the problem is `dataString = "";`. Try switching to a fixed size buffer and I think you'll solve the problem